# Question about the derivative of distance vs displacment.

Tags: calculus

Displacement and Distance are not exactly the same things. I have seen everywhere on the Internet that the derivative of a distance function is it's velocity function, however to my understanding this is not true. The derivative of displacement* is velocity. Is my understanding correct, and what then is the first and second derivative of a distance function.

Comment: The derivative in a sense is calculating a change in one variable to another at an instant and in these cases we are referring to a change in time . And your displacement is actually measuring the absolute distance in a way

Comment: What are your definitions of displacement and distance?

Comment: Displacement is the shortest length from an initial position to a final position, distance is the total length traveled regardless of direction.

Comment: Ahmed, people just speak loosely sometimes. I wouldn't worry about it too much unless it's the case that the person *is* trying to be precise and there *is* a mismatch in units. In 1D, people quite often use "distance" to mean "signed distance". You usually see more precise language in higher dimensions, i.e. motion in 2D and 3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more correct to say that velocity is the derivative of position. It's the instantaneous measure of how position changes with respect to time.

The difference between displacement and distance is that distance is a scalar valued function where-as displacement is a vector, it's an arrow. Suppose for example that a particle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has position: 
[image: position]

Consider finding the velocity at the black point. Let's measure displacement from the origin (displacement is independent of observer). Velocity is the change of displacement over time. The change in displacement gives the yellow lines below. You can see they are secant lines. Hence in the limit you get the usual derivative:

[image: displacement]

If instead you were to consider distance, you would be computing the length of small arcs centered at the black point.

If you take the limit of the quotient of these arcs over time you get a scalar. What's cool is that this scalar is the length of the limit vector from the quotient of the yellow lines above.